# whonix and location of hidden_service?

Tags: onion-services, whonix

I am newbie, first time I try whonix, I didn't find in workstation hidden_service in torrc file and gateway station show me /etc/tor/torrc but there is nothing, I added two lines:
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 80 192.168.0.11:80

so, I don't know how to install Tor hidden service, I followed https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Hidden_Services
I installed also lighttpd in workstation but it failed to start, maybe because port 80 is already occupied.
in gateway, cd var/lib/tor says permission denied.
maybe there is hidden_service folder? I see, owner is debian-tor and I am user in whonix.

what should I do to install testing website as Tor hidden service? I just want to try it and without success.

I did chmod and added index.html beside private_key and hostname but when I try to use Tor browser bundle to connect, no success.

Answer (score 5):

In the gateway VM, your hidden service specification goes in `/etc/tor/torrc`. By default, it's largely empty, and the default configuration has been moved to `/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc`. In `/etc/tor/torrc`, add something like this for a webserver:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/my_hidden_website/
HiddenServicePort 80 192.168.0.11:80
```

You need to restart Tor to generate the hidden service key and hostname:

```
user@host:~$ sudo service tor restart
```

Then get the hostname:

```
user@host:~$ sudo cat /var/lib/tor/my_hidden_website/hostname
```

Now, working in the workstation VM, install lighttpd. Once installed, it starts at bootup. Your website root directory is `/var/www/` on the workstation VM. It is NOT `/var/lib/tor/my_hidden_website/` on the gateway VM. That would be a very bad thing, especially if you somehow made it work!

Using another machine running Tor Browser Bundle, browse your hidden-service hostname: `http://mynewthshostname.onion`. You should see the lighttpd's default page. Once you have that working, you can replace the lighttpd default with your website.

Comment: How do I know what the IP of my workstation vm should be here?

Answer (score 2):

> I didn't find in workstation hidden_service in torrc file and gateway station show me /etc/tor/torrc but there is nothing

There little non-nothingness in [/etc/tor/torrc](https://github.com/Whonix/Whonix/blob/master/whonix_gateway/etc/tor/torrc.whonix) worth reading. It says `Please see /etc/tor/torrc.examples for help, options, comments etc.`

Having a look at [/etc/tor/torrc.examples](https://github.com/Whonix/Whonix/blob/master/whonix_gateway/etc/tor/torrc.examples) as well.

> cd /var/lib/tor says permission denied

You need to be `root` (or `debian-tor`) to get into that folder.

Comment: Yes, adrelanos and associates have locked down Whonix ;)

Comment: This particular move shipping an almost empty torrc isn't about lock down. Also permissions of /var/lib/tor come with upstream Tor, no changes there. There move to ship an almost empty `/etc/tor/torrc` was made to leave that file untouched when Whonix is updated. The goal is users not to prompt with an interactive dpkg conflict resolution dialog. `/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc` and `/etc/tor/torrc.examples` can be updated in further Whonix versions without conflicting with user changes in `/etc/tor/torrc`.

Comment: Ah, I get it :)